# calculateDistances() function doesn't work taking start/end value from a select

Tags: html-select, distance

I'd like to calculate the distance between 2 points, taking coordinates for each point from a select. The following is the code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calcola il tuo itinerario</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 20%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        width: 300px;
      }

      /*
      Provide the following styles for both ID and class,
      where ID represents an actual existing "panel" with
      JS bound to its name, and the class is just non-map
      content that may already have a different ID with
      JS bound to its name.
      */

      #panel, .panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      #panel select, #panel input, .panel select, .panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #panel select, .panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #panel i, .panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }<br>

      #outputDiv {
        font-size: 11px;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
          var chiesamadre = new google.maps.LatLng(37.485558, 13.987883);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom:17,
            center: chiesamadre
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }

        function calcRoute() {
          var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
          var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
          var request = {
              origin:start,
              destination:end,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
          });
        }   

        function calculateDistances() {
          var start = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('start').value);
          var end = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('end').value);
          var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
          service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
              origin:start,
              destination:end,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
              avoidHighways: false,
              avoidTolls: false
            }, callback);
        }

        function callback(response, status) {
          if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
          } else {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
            outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
            deleteOverlays();

            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              addMarker(origins[i], false);
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                addMarker(destinations[j], true);
                outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
                    + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
                    + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
              }
            }
          }
        }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="panel">
        <b>Partenza: </b>
        <select id="start" onChange="calcRoute();">
          <option value="37.485558, 13.987883">Chiesa Madre</option>
          <option value="37.484813, 13.983602">Calvario</option>
          <option value="37.484474, 13.986312">Torre civica con orologi</option>
          <option value="37.485703, 13.986480">Chiesa di San Giuseppe</option>
          <option value="37.491049, 13.988843">Torre Con Orologi Cristo re</option>
          <option value="37.484507, 13.989363">Chiesa Santa Maria del Rosario</option>
          <option value="37.472353, 13.945771">Vassallaggi</option>
        </select>
        <b>Arrivo: </b>
        <select id="end" onChange="calcRoute();">
          <option value="37.485558, 13.987883">Chiesa Madre</option>
          <option value="37.484813, 13.983602">Calvario</option>
          <option value="37.484474, 13.986312">Torre civica con orologi</option>
          <option value="37.485703, 13.986480">Chiesa di San Giuseppe</option>
          <option value="37.491049, 13.988843">Torre Con Orologi Cristo re</option>
          <option value="37.484507, 13.989363">Chiesa Santa Maria del Rosario</option>
          <option value="37.472353, 13.945771">Vassallaggi</option>
        </select>
            <b>Distanza: </b>
             <p><button type="button" onClick="calculateDistances();">Calculate
              distances</button></p>
         <p> <div id="outputDiv"></div></p>
        </div>

            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`calcRoute()` function works fine but `calculateDistances()` function doesn't work, in fact if I click on the "Calculate distances" button after selecting start and end, no text is showed in the white space on the button, where is the div with the expected result of calculated distance. Maybe I did something wrong with the `start` and `end` variables of `calculateDistances()` function. I added this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnq91j0c/
and this is the link of the page online: http://turismosancataldo.it/calcolo-itinerario-piedi-dist.html

How to fix the function? Thank You for any help.

Comment: Why do you say it does not work? What does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I edited to question to make it more clear. There is a lot of missing data like the code you pasted is not complete like it doesn't have a starting `script` tag but has a closing `script` tag. You should be more clear in what the code is supposed to do like an expected output and current output etc. Its good to add a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to your question to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Ram I try to use JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnq91j0c/ The url of the page is: http://turismosancataldo.it/calcolo-itinerario-piedi-dist.html As You can see from this link, calcRoute() function works fine. But 'calculateDistances' function doesn't work, infact if I click on Calculate distances, no text is showed in the white space on the button, where is the div with the result of calculated distance. I try to change var start but doesn't works. I can't post all code beacause there aren't enought characters, and if I add it as aswer, it's deleted. I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: Please edit the question by clicking on [edit](http://imgur.com/VDtAGqd) under the question and add the code and your comment into the question.

Comment: Thank You @Ram for the screenshot, I haven't seen the link, sorry.
I updated the question with all code and explaining better the expected output. I added the JSfiddle and the url of the page on line. Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Please updated the title to better reflect your question no one will understand the question looking at the title and will ignore your question.

Comment: @Ram I have updated the title of my question. Hope to receive some answere. Thank You

Comment: @Vilsepi can You help me?